# How to configure HttpClient message handlers after WebApplicationBuilder has been built?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

How do I configure HttpClient message handlers *after* the WebApplication has been built?

Looking at the documentation it appears the only way to configure the HttpClient message handlers is by using named HttpClients, but named clients can only be configured during application startup before the WebApplication is built. My application will not know what HttpClient configurations will be required until after the web service initialisation is complete.

My specific scenario is as follows:

I have an .Net 6 ASP Core web service that needs to send requests to multiple servers.

These outgoing requests use mTLS and message signing so I need to configure each HttpClient's primary message handler with the certificate to use and a custom delegating message handler.

My web service has a different client identity wrt to each of the other servers that it contacts. So each HttpClient needs to be configured to use a different certificate.

The services my web service connects is not known until after the web service initialisation is compelete.

How can I do this?

Comment: _"but named clients can only be configured during application startup before the 
WebApplication is built"_ - Yes-and-no. Dynamic and post-startup registration of named `HttpClient` is undocumented but works consistently in every version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` I've ever used. See this GitHub issue I filed here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36378